# CSS menu, help to remove style in ul li list

Tags: html, css

Need help adding a button in ul-list

My site is located at www.svenskasjoar.se and i whant to add a small uk-flag (25x16px) to the right of "RBN" in the menu.

The menu is built with:

```
<ul class="glossymenu">
<li<? if ($self == "index") { echo " class=\"current\""; }?>><a href="index.php"><b>Start</b></a></li>
<li<? if ($self == "blog") { echo " class=\"current\""; }?>><a href="blog.php"><b>Blogg</b></a></li>
```

CSS:

```
.glossymenu{
position: relative;
padding: 0 0 0 0px;
margin: -15px auto 0 0;  /* 0 auto 0 auto; */
background: url(media/menub_bg.gif) repeat-x; /*tab background image path*/
height: 46px;
list-style: none;
}

.glossymenu li{
float:left;
}

.glossymenu li a{
float: left;
display: block;
color:#000;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
padding:0 0 0 16px; /*Padding to accomodate left tab image. Do not change*/
height: 46px;
line-height: 46px;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;    
}

.glossymenu li a b{
float: left;
display: block;
padding: 0 24px 0 8px; /*Padding of menu items*/
}

.glossymenu li.current a, .glossymenu li a:hover{
color: #fff;
background: url(media/menub_hover_left.gif) no-repeat; /*left tab image path*/
background-position: left;
}

#glossymenuuk{
color: #1ff;
background: none;
//background: url(media/menub_hover_left.gif) no-repeat; /*left tab image path*/
//background-position: left;
}

.glossymenu li.current a b, .glossymenu li a:hover b{
color: #fff;
background: url(media/menub_hover_right.gif) no-repeat right top; /*right tab image path*/
}

.glossymenu li.current a, .glossymenu li a:active{
color: #fff;
background: url(media/menub_hover_left.gif) no-repeat; /*left tab image path*/
background-position: left;
}

.glossymenu li.current a b, .glossymenu li a:active b{
color: #fff;
background: url(media/menub_hover_right.gif) no-repeat right top; /*right tab image path*/
}
```

Now, how can i edit the CSS to display the flag as an menu item (or just an clickablle image link)? The flag shall not be styled in any way, and the background hover shall not be visible when hovering over the flag.

Completely lost here |-: CSS is like Black Magic
Have tried addressing id with #name but no change.

Answer (score 0):

Use li:before selector

Like this

```
li:before{
  display: inline-block;
  content: ' ';
  background: ('path_to_your_flag') no-repeat 0 0;
  width: 30px; /*size of pic*/
  height: 30px:
}

li a{
padding-left: 40px;
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work - places some of the menu items on row 2 and places the flag between every menu item. Flag not cklickable

Comment: Did some additional tests. If i add an ul:after in CSS i can Place the flag but how do i get it clickable? Would be better with a separate styl on a li iten...

Comment: Solved indirectly by the tip!